# Filter HTML Code out of Website (cache it) and load it into WebView (RegEx)

Tags: android, html, regex, filter

I am relativly new to programming in java and android, so I wanted to ask you guys for a **simple and understandable** way of filtering two tables and their h3 headings of [this website](http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html), possibly even cache it, and load it into a transparent WebView, so it doesnt look like a website. *I thought of **RegEx***.. I do this to keep it up to date without having to service that thing.
With "simple and understandable" I mean comments, and possibly show what are just var names, method names or other custom names. And many explanations, comments and other things... Of course you can also just bomb the code in there, that would also work but I probably could not understand all of it.. ;)

Here's some code I tried:

```
package com.mrousavy.gemeindemuckendorfwipfing;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by Marc on 15.10.2015.
 */
public class Table {

// found on stackoverflow
public static boolean exists2(String url) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        connection.connect();
        return connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * must NOT be called in main thread!!!
 */
public static String getHTML2(String url) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
        String tmp, html = "";
        while ((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            html += tmp;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return html;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * must NOT be called in main thread!!!
 */
public static List<String> getUrlsFromHTML2(String html) throws Exception {
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList();

    //init Patterns
    Pattern divsPattern = Pattern.compile("<h3>.</table>");
    //Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"\\./files/(.*?)\"");

    //search for right divs
    Matcher divs = divsPattern.matcher(html);
    while (divs.find()) {
        //search for links
        String innerDiv = divs.group(1);
        Matcher url = urlPattern.matcher(innerDiv);
        if (url.find()) {
            if (!urls.contains(url.group(1)))
                urls.add(url.group(1));
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return urls;
}

public static List<News> getNewsFromHTML(String html) {
    List<News> ret = new ArrayList();

    Pattern firstNewsPattern = Pattern.compile("<h3><strong>Aktuelle Meldungen</strong></h3>(.*?)<hr />");
    Pattern newsPattern = Pattern.compile("<hr />(.*?)<hr />");
    Pattern newsHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("<h4>(.*?)</h4>");
    Pattern hrefPattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher newsHeader = null;
    Matcher href = null;

    Matcher firstNews = firstNewsPattern.matcher(html);
    if(firstNews.find()) {
        String content = firstNews.group(1).replace("./", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/");
        href = hrefPattern.matcher(content);
        while(href.find()) {
            String url = href.group(1);
            if(!url.contains("/")) {
                content = content.replace("href=\"" + url + "\"", "href=\"" + "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/" + url + "\"");
            }
        }
        newsHeader = newsHeaderPattern.matcher(content);
        if(newsHeader.find())
            ret.add(new News(newsHeader.group(1).replaceAll("<(.*?)>", "").replaceAll("&#\\d{4};", ""), content));
    }

    Matcher news = newsPattern.matcher(html);
    while(news.find()) {
        String content = news.group(1).replace("./", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/");
        href = hrefPattern.matcher(content);
        while(href.find()) {
            String url = href.group(1);
            if(!url.contains("/")) {
                content = content.replace("href=\"" + url + "\"", "href=\"" + "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/" + url + "\"");
            }
        }
        newsHeader = newsHeaderPattern.matcher(content);
        if(newsHeader.find())
            ret.add(new News(newsHeader.group(1).replaceAll("<(.*?)>", "").replaceAll("&#\\d{4};", ""), content));
    }

    return ret;
}

public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    String ret = "";
    for(String str : list) {
        ret += str + "§";
    }
    ret = ret.substring(0, ret.length()-1);
    return ret;
}

public static List<String> stringToList(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split("§");
    List <String> ret = new ArrayList();
    for(String s : arr) {
        if(!s.trim().equals(""))
            ret.add(s);
    }
    return ret;
}

public static String extractContentFromHTML(String html) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<div id=\"content\">((.*?(<div.*?<\\/div>)*.*?)*)<\\/div>");
    Pattern hrefPattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");

    Matcher match = regex.matcher(html);
    if(match.find()) {
        String content = match.group(1).replace("./", "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/");
        Matcher href = hrefPattern.matcher(content);
        while(href.find()) {
            String url = href.group(1);
            if(!url.contains("/")) {
                content = content.replace("href=\"" + url + "\"", "href=\"" + "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/" + url + "\"");
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
    return "";
}

}
```

I hope someone can help me out! :)

Thank you! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse html/xml, it's error prone. Try using specialized lib as the excellent [**Jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

[...]
final String url = "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html";

String tablesHtml = parseHTML(url);
[...]


String parseHTML(String url) {
  //Retrieve html of {url} via GET
  Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

  //Parse html
  Document doc = response.parse();

  //Select the div with id="content", where both tables are stored
  Element contentDiv = doc.select("div#content").first();

  //return the inner html of <div id="content"> selected above
  return contentDiv.html();
}
```

The syntax of the select function can be found [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

**UPDATE**: i've updated the code to parse the content of div too, creating a Table class that store `<h3>` text and table as 'html' and also as a bidimensional String array. It has a nice toString() method too useful to see what you get.

*NB*: The trick is in the jsoup select statement `"h3:contains(" + h3Text + ") ~ table"`: it selects the tables after and h3 tag with `h3Text` (the title of the table) inside. Later we're taking only the first table of the list so we can be sure we're selecting the table coupled with the h3 title.

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

//[...]

/* //CASE 1: if you have to download the html
 * String url = "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html";
 * //Retrieve html of "url" via GET
 * Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
 * //Parse html
 *Document doc = response.parse();
 */

//CASE 2: If you already have the html in a String called htmlString
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

//Select the div with id="content", where both tables are stored
Element contentDiv = doc.select("div#content").first();
//Create a list for the data
List tables = new ArrayList<Table>();
//Loop on h3 titles and get the coupled table below
for ( Element h3 : contentDiv.select("h3") )
{
  //get the text inside <h3> tag
  String h3Text = h3.text();
  //jsoup select statement to get the table
  //immediately after the <h3></h3>
  String select = "h3:contains(" + h3Text + ") ~ table";
  //Actually get the jsoup table element jTable
  Element jTable = contentDiv.select(select).first();
  //Load the data on the list
  tables.add(new Table(h3Text,jTable));
}

//print them
for ( Table t : tables )
  System.out.println(t);

//[...]

class Table 
{
  String     h3Title;
  String     htmlTable;
  String[][] splittedTable;

  Table(String h3Title, Element jTable)
  {
    this.h3Title       = h3Title;
    this.htmlTable     = jTable.html();
    this.splittedTable = getSplittedTable(jTable);
  }

  String[][] getSplittedTable(Element jTable)
  {
    //Get all the rows of the jTable
    Elements trs      = jTable.select("tr");
    //Get the number of rows
    int rows          = trs.size();
    //Get the columns of the first row (the same of all the rows)
    int columns       = trs.first().select("td").size();
    //Allocate new bidimensional array table
    String[][] table = new String[rows][columns];
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    for ( Element tr : trs ) {
      for ( Element td : tr.select("td") ) {
        table[i][j++] = td.text();
      }
      j = 0; //reset column cursor
      i++;   //increment row cursor
    }
    return table;
  }

  @Override
  String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String ln        = System.lineSeparator();

    sb.append(h3Title + ln);
    sb.append("--" + ln);
    sb.append(this.htmlTable + ln);
    sb.append("--" + ln);
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedTable.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < splittedTable[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(splittedTable[i][j] + " | ")
      }
      sb.append(ln + "--" + ln);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this only return content div? I already got this... I still have to filter the two h3s and tables out.. :/

Comment: @mrousavy: i've updated the code to get content of ``<h3>`` and ``<table>`` too. In the Table class the content of ``<table>`` is available as html code and as a bidimensional array too.

Comment: Is this minSdk 16? I don't know why but Response and Jsoup cannot be resolved... I think I understand it, but I don't know what I'm missing... :/

Comment: @mrousavy: you have to add jsoup to your project as external dependency. Are you using Android Studio? You can download the jar from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3/jsoup-1.8.3.jar), download it and place in your classpath or add the dependency to ``projectRoot/build.gradle`` (in the dependencies section of file add a line with ``'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'``). If you tell me the path of your project (and if it is an AndroidStudio project) i can give you more detailed instruction, if needed.

Comment: C:\Users\Marc\AndroidStudioProjects\GemeindeMuckendorfWipfing Okay, so where should I put that jar? And also, I already have the whole HTML Code in a String, do I still need all of your code just for getting all between the div id="content" tag? ... And if I just add it in dependencies, it still can't resolve Connection, Jsoup, Document, Element, etc... :/ Still too much errors

Comment: Place that jar here: ``C:\Users\Marc\AndroidStudioProjects\GemeindeMuckendorfWipfing\app\libs\jsoup-1.8.3.jar``. From AndroidStudio on the left pane in ``Project`` mode, right click the jar file and 'Add as library...'. This will add the jar file as a dependency.

Comment: @mrousavy: check the updated code, i've added a _CASE 2_ which parse the html directly from String.

Comment: I really appreciate it that you help me out here, even if I'm such a noobie still in Java... :D For that - Thank you very much!!
I understand the code a little bit, but I am confused, because it's that much.. And I still get IOException errors, also it can't find Table... :/
Should I post the code somewhere?
Error:(45, 27) error: cannot find symbol class ArrayList
Error:(45, 37) error: cannot find symbol class Table
And also, I have written a method earlier for getting the HTML, but that also throws me an IOException since today.. I don't know why.. :/

Comment: @mrousavy: i don't want to tell you what to do but the philosophy of this site is: 1 request / 1 question (it's difficult that anyone can benefit from these comments) . If you want you can accept this answer (only if you think it's appropriate and to balance my effort) and open a new one with your request, trying to explain why does not work.

Comment: @mrousavy: anyway save the ``Table {... lines of code ...}`` code into a Table.java file placed in the same package (directory) of the class containing jsoup code (another file with .java extension). Import java.util.ArrayList in the file with jsoup also. You can post your code on github.com (or equivalent)

Comment: Oh okay I see.. I'm sorry... But thanks for your help!

Comment: @mrousavy: don't worry about your requests, everyone is here to learn something new. Try to do clear and linear questions and provide your attempts (code or strategies) to answer them.

Comment: Okay I made a new Post, but as you can see I really need this done until tomorrow... :D I hope you can somehow help me out...

Comment: @mrousavy: 1 problem / 1 question on stackoverflow (and this is not a code writing/review service): you put all the problems together alongside with the unclear question of this post. Accept this answer at least if you found my code useful, and ask for a specific task (if you can't already find it on internet). Something like [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/) can solve your Jsoup not on main thread /  AsyncTask problem.